# Emojis not displaying in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, emoji

I'm using [jQuery Emoji Picker](https://github.com/wedgies/jquery-emoji-picker) to display unicode emojis in textareas and inputs.  However, they are not displaying in certain textareas, despite the emoji being placed in the textarea and able to be copied-and-pasted from it. How can I get them to display?

Comment: Please post the code you have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out having `font-weight: bold;` prohibited the emojis from displaying.  Setting `font-weight: normal;` solved it!